# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0?

Tags: c#, json

I have an issue in Newtonsoft.json library. When i try to run project using visual studio, it's working properly. But when i tried to create .exe on this, it shows a run time error

```
    Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, 

Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependancies.

 The system cannot find the file specified.
```

In refereence and bin folder newsoft.json file available. Also in package folder also available.
Why this error triggers only when i create .exe?
Please help me..

Comment: Did you put the Newtonsoft.Json.dll file together with your exe file?

Comment: No, it should load right when tried to create .exe on this.

Comment: Then I suggest you copy the dll file to the folder where your exe locates.

Comment: its not good going.. because when end user uses this .exe file,if they deleted this dll by mistake, then this application won't work right.

Comment: @Arya That's how applications work. You can't just go deleting bits of them and expect them to not crash. If your users are doing stupid things like that it's their problem not yours.

Comment: You can use ILMerge to combine it into a single exe.  I've done think many times with the Newtonsoft library.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Installed Costura.Fody library file. Now its working as expected.

Comment: This answer makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but my project was a console application made with .Net full, referencing another .Net standard project which had the NewntonSoft referenced.
Both projects needs to use package management the same way. This article explains this better:

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReferencingNETStandardAssembliesFromBothNETCoreAndNETFramework.aspx

Answer (score 1):

.NET projects are not normally run as a standalone *.exe file.

You're choice is either create a setup project for your program or to copy the whole `bin\Release` folder. This folder should contain all the necessary non-standard libraries (the standard .NET libraries are provided by the operating system).

Comment: when creating .exe, all library available in bin\release folder. But i copied .exe to desktop. That time it shows error.

Comment: @Arya: How did you create the .exe file?

Comment: @aray. You have to copy the whole folder, not just the *.exe file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to match the versions of the package on all the sub projects, by upgrading on it.